# setFocus not working with react-hook-form in a dialog component

Tags: react-hook-form

I’m having an issue with react-hook-form’s setFocus function. I’m trying to focus an input field (username) in a SignInDialog component when the dialog is opened, but it’s not working. I’ve tried several approaches, including using useEffect to call setFocus when the dialog is opened and forwarding the ref prop to the underlying input element, but nothing seems to work.

Here’s a link to a code sandbox that reproduces the issue: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/signindialog-smhpmx?file=%2Fsrc%2FSignInDialog.jsx%3A10%2C14

Can anyone help me figure out what’s going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your effect hook runs immediately because your `SignInDialog` component is always mounted/rendered, but the focus call can't focus anything because the input is not there yet.

You can either add another flag to the deps, for example:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (openSignInDialog) {
      // It also does not work without timeout
      setTimeout(() => {
        setFocus("username");
      });
    }
  }, [setFocus, openSignInDialog]);
```

But the easier way would be to just pass `autoFocus` props to your `TextFieldStyled`.